# WMI "string embedded instance"

Tags: c#, wmi

I am investigating making WMI calls to manipulate VHDs from c# (Yes I know powershell already has cmdlets to do this, this is somewhat of an academic exercise).

I’m using this (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh850163(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
\\.\ROOT\virtualization\v2:Msvm_ImageManagementService
```

I am attempting to call the CreateVirtualHardDisk method, however it takes a "String that contains an embedded instance of the Msvm_VirtualHardDiskSettingsData class"

As such I'm not sure how to convert my Msvm_VirtualHardDiskSettingsData instance into this sort of string.

There must be an API somewhere to convert WMI objects to and from string embedded instances. Can someone help me find this?

Comment: Yes, I tried google.

Comment: See if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21424490/113116) and [this](http://www.getcodesamples.com/src/2D4BC0AA/48B4B5FC) help.

Answer (score 0):

If it's still relevant, it looks like you can obtain the embedded instance through a call to [GetVirtualHardDiskSettingData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh850064(v=vs.85).aspx)

For more information see the [Msvm_VirtualHardDiskSettingData class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh850248(v=vs.85).aspx):

> When the Msvm_ImageManagementService.GetVirtualHardDiskSettingData method returns an instance of Msvm_VirtualHardDiskSettingData, the client can use this property to get the unique disk ID of the VHD.